# C dead code detection while using ARM compiler

Tags: c, function, pointers, embedded, dead-code

I am working on embedded systems.
I use **C** to program and **ARM** compiler to compile.

The code I am working on has been around for sometime an has been developed by multiple people. It uses **function pointers** as well.

Are there any tools that may help me to detect dead code?
If not, how do you suggest I go about it?

Comment: Increase level of compiler optimization and [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) and [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_analysis) may help you.

Answer (score 5):

The ARM linker supports *cross-module optimisation* which will remove unused functions within object modules (including class member functions).  Dead code within a function will be dealt with by the optimizer.

If you want to actually remove the code from the source, then a static analysis tool will be able to detect similar dead code sections to those that the compiler optimiser can detect.

Comment: how do I go about removing dead code that involves function pointers?
do I read the actual function table/do a reference count?

Comment: @user1928721: You probably can't; function pointer's are variables that can be assigned and modified at run-time. At compile-time you may not have enough information to know a function is never assigned to a function pointer and/or the function is not called through that pointer.  If there is enough information (i.e. the function is never referenced) the linker will spot it in any case - the linker map file will list all functions removed by cross-module optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the feedback linker option? It creates a file with a list of unused functions.

See [ARM Compiler toolchain Linker Reference > --feedback=file](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0493c/CHDBDCIE.html)